# Alignment is weird

Tags: steering, alignment

I just replaced the cv axle on my car after hitting a curb. I changed the cv and took it to a shop to get a alignment it was right and they showed me the print out from the alignment rack, but when I’m driving sometimes it will slowly drift out of alignment also sometimes I hear a popping when I turn the wheel can someone help me out if they have any ideas on what it can be.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You state "it will slowly drift out of alignment" ... are you meaning to say if you let go of the steering wheel momentarily, it will wander left or right? If so, is the direction random or always the same direction? Is there any pull at all in the steering wheel?

Comment: I suspect there was more damage to the suspension when you hit the curb and it was missed by the alignment shop. Popping is not good.

Comment: Some joint could be broken which sits correct when stationary so the alignment shop won’t see it and you missed it when you checked for damage after hitting the curb.